# Find null and fill with a correspondent value based on another columns value

Tags: python, pandas, targetnullvalue

If on column A I have the ID number of people, and column B I have their names, but I have many rows where the ID is entered but the name is missing, assuming, same person, same Id and supposedly same name.

How can I to locate null on column B, grab correspondent value on A(ID#), compare and find the name ID and them grab the name(value on B) and fill the null value? Like:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 56 | Michael |
| 34 | Paula |
| 79 | Davi |
| 80 | Luna |
| 56 | NaN |

So I want a code to identify the `NaN`, grab the A column value 56, search for another 56 in the same column and fill `NaN` with the correspondent value, imagine this dataframe is gigantic, so I can't just group by A and replace one by one

Comment: you can try `df.groupby('A')['B'].ffill()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comment, `ffill` can work. But if `NaN` value appears first in the group, it won't change that `NaN`. So sort df by 'B' first and then do `ffill` like:

```
df.sort_values('B', ignore_index=True, inplace=True)
df['B'] = df.groupby('A')['B'].ffill()
```

Or you can find what is the real name of each id by dropping NaN and map it onto the 'A' column:

```
df['B'] = df['A'].map(df.groupby('A').agg(lambda x:x.dropna().unique())['B'])
```

Although ffill might be more performant without considering sort.

Comment: I want to read what is written in your profile picture, but it's not very clear, can you please tell me what is that?

Comment: If the first value will be NaN, I think we can put it as `df.groupby('A')['B'].ffill().bfill()`? Save the hassle of sorting it

Comment: @KevinChoonLiangYew No that won't work, because after ffill it is not necessary that the similar 'A' are adjacent and hence bfill will actually fill the value of other 'A'. You can do bfill after another groupby. But I think sort and ffill is more performant.

Comment: @SunderamDubey it can be read if you try ;)